# RecyclerView when using notifyItemRemoved, the method onMeasure() in LayoutManager doesn't run

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've create a CustomGridLayoutManager that can adjust `layout_height` automatically.

However, when I use method `notifyItemRemoved()`, the `onMeasure()` in LayoutManager doesn't run.

I had searched the source codes but there seems to be no method such as `view.invalidate()` or `postInvalidate()` in LayoutManager, and the method `requestLayout()`in LayoutManager is calling `RecyclerView.requestLayout()`, it doesn't work as well.

So if I want to notify the LayoutManager running it's `onMeasure()` method, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that I had a line that recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)...

I don't know when I add this code and with delete it, it works well.